# Xcode: self-adjusting font size depending on how a much text is in a text field

Tags: iphone, ios, text, uilabel, adjustable

I have created a UIlabel and UItextfield that correspond with each other. My new challenge is to have my font self-adjust its size to fill the UIlabel depending on how much text is entered. Solutions?

Answer (score 3):

`UILabel` has a property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. Please refer to [UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).

`UITextField` has a same one, see [UITextField Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UItextfield_Class/Reference/UItextfield.html).

You can set a big enough default font size and let the control reduce the text to fit the width. The actual font size will be between `minimumFontSize` and the size setting of `font`.